# jquery mobile select - get rid of the icon (1.2)

Tags: jquery, mobile

I can't get rid of the icon in the select menu for jquery mobile. I tried using data-iconpos as selected in earlier questions but it doesn't seem to work (see jsfiddle).

```
<label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
                <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0" data-iconpos="none">
                   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                   <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select>​
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggSBu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(".ui-select .ui-icon").remove();​​​
```

Here's an updated version of your fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/ggSBu/1/